# Find $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\int_0^x(e^{2t}+t)^{1/t}dt}{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

It's asked to solve this:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\int_0^x(e^{2t}+t)^{1/t}dt}{x}$$

And I have no idea how to do it...

Comment: Have you tried applying L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: So applying L'H I get $\lim_{x\to 0}(e^{2x}+x)^{1/x}$, so the answer is $\infty$?

Comment: Not quite. Substituting $x=0$ would give you $1^\infty$, which is actually an indeterminate form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see this as the derivative of the function

$$F(x)=\int_0^x(e^{2t}+t)^{1/t}dt$$

At $x=0$ because $F(0)=0$

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\int_0^x(e^{2t}+t)^{1/t}dt-0}{x-0}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x-0}=F'(0)$$

Which by the fundamental theorem of calculus is equal to the function inside of the integral evaluated at $t=0$. But it happens that this value is not defined. So is needed to extend the function $(e^{2t}+t)^{\frac{1}{t}}$ continuously at $t=0$; this does not change the integral, and we can apply the FTC to the primitive of the extended function.

To compute that continuous extension, we need to compute a new limit which is the value  of the function as $t \to 0$.

$$\lim_{t \to 0}(e^{2t}+t)^{1/t}=\exp{\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\ln(e^{2t}+t)}{t}}$$
$$=\exp{\frac{d}{dt}\left(\ln{(e^{2t}+t)}\right)_{t=0}}=\exp{\left(\frac{2e^{2t}+1}{e^{2t}+t}\right)_{t=0}}=\exp{3}$$

Comment: I don't follow the exp and ln step... I mean, you take ln on the fraction, and add exp to the left side, why?

Comment: When you have a limit $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ you can write it as $\lim_{x \to a}\exp  (\ln  f(x))=\exp  \left(\lim_{x \to a}\ln  f(x)\right)$ because $\exp$ is continous function.

Comment: exp(xxxx) notation means $e^{(xxxx)}$, right?

Comment: yes is the same. $\exp(x)=e^{x}$

Comment: Thank you and excuse me the amount of questions, I'm just so stressed. Thank you again.

Comment: @JoãoPedro no problem. I hope it helped

Comment: I think the formulation could be improved a bit. Where you say "is equal to the function inside of the integral" this refers to the value of that function at $0$. But it happens that this value is not defined. So what you do is try to extend the function $(e^{2t}+t)^{1/t}$ continuously at $t=0$; this does not change the integral, and you can apply the FTC to the primitive of the extended function. To compute that continuous extension, you need to compute a _new_ limit (which then proceeds as indicated).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen thanks a lot, could you please see if now is right? (more or less a copy paste of your comment)

Comment: @rlartiga: Looks fine now.

Answer (score 5):

L'Hopital's rule is only step 1:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\int_0^x(e^{2t}+t)^{1/t}}{x}
=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{ \frac{d}{dx} \left(\int_0^x(e^{2t}+t)^{1/t}\right) }{1} = 
\lim_{x \to 0}(e^{2x}+x)^{1/x}
$$
The next step is to expand $e^{2x}$:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}(e^{2x}+x)^{1/x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\left([1+2x+O(x^2)] + x\right)^{1/x}  = \lim_{x \to 0}\left(1+3x\right)^{1/x} = e^3
$$

Comment: What is this O?

Comment: Sorry man I'm just sick of this teacher. I'm graduating in engeneering and she is taking our skin out and her questions asks for more than needed, I'm exploiting this website.

Comment: For example, I'm in Calculus II and in Calculus I I never saw this f***** limit.

Comment: The expression $O(x^k)$ means "some function of $x$ that goes to zero sufficiently rapidly as x goes to zero that $\lim_{x\to 0}$ of that function divided by $x^k$ exists."

Comment: Thank you, Mark. That was usefull.

Comment: And in the context of this problem, what it means is that the terms beyond $2x$ in the expansion of $e^{2x}$ can safely be ignored.

Comment: Where can I find more information about this expansion of $e^{2x}$ I'm just having trouble figuring this out...